# Getting " SQLGrammarException: Invalid object name " on fetching table data

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-mvc

previously my project(Spring and Hibernate integrated) connected with mysql now i am trying to connect with SQL server 2005, in entire project i am using HQL query and when i am trying to fetch data from the table it giving error as fallow

```
Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_, role0_.description as descript2_1_, role0_.name as name1_ from easylibSQL.role role0_

WARN [localhost-startStop-1] SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(143) | SQL Error: 208, SQLState: 42S02
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(144) | Invalid object name 'easylibSQL.role'.
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Invalid object name 'easylibSQL.role'.
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1926)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2411)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2397)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2227)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2222)
```

But if i use Native SQL query then it execute fine, how can i resolve this problem. I searched over the net but did't got valid solution.

i refereed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287393/invalid-object-name-hiberate-3-6) but the error was same, in my case all tables are having a id primary key with auto incremented value. I annotated the Id as follow in POJO class

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @DocumentId
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

and i tried with this but no use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution I replaced all the columns datatype having Bigint to int, so it's working fine